# php url rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

I have tried all i could up to no avail, checked all web tutorials on url `.htaccess` rewriting, none solved all my problem exclusively, my programming experts help me with this, i have a php web application, the .htaccess code I have only manages url's without the .php extension, like `localhost/app/images.php`, the link is `localhost/app/images`, once you click on it, .htaccess understands `/images` is `/images.php` and fetches the document, but when i tried to put some more .htaccess code to rewrite some dynamic links like `/images/miscellaneous` where the right link should be

```
/images.php?album_id=miscellaneous
```

i get

```
internal server error
```

This is the .htaccess code i have now, it only matches /images to /images.php

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ansjc
# Remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
RewriteRule images/album_id/(.*)/ images.php?album_id=$1
RewriteRule images/album_id/(.*) images.php?album_id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules have two major problems:

- the order of them matters. Right now, your second and third will never match stuff
- two of them could be simplified into one.

Consider using this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /ansjc
 # Remove file extension
 RewriteRule images/album_id/(.+)/?$ images.php?album_id=$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

The [L] flag signifies "last". In other words, if it matches, nothing else will be processed in terms of rewrites. So, if images/album_id/etc/ gets matched, the second rewrite rule will not interfere.

This also solves the issue of the .php being appended to everything. Though I suspect your 500 might be from your code, not from rewrites.

Comment: This solution works but removes the stylesheets, and no data is displayed, i think i'm the one making the mistake, this is how my link starts: echo "<li class='album'><a href='images/$title'> so once the link is clicked, i want .htaccess to pass the variables to the page images.php?album_id=Miscellaneous

Comment: @NwachukwuAlNnaemeka: remember that images.php suddenly does not magically understand that it is now two directories down from where it used to be. IF your stylesheets and images are specified relatively (href="css/styles.css"), you'll need to adjust those to be absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ images.php?album_id=$1 [L]
```

and try

```
http://localhost/images
http://localhost/images/
http://localhost/images/album_id
```

it will call images.php and inside images.php just print_r($_GET); to test.